createRouter is not defined in Vue Js
working with Vue Js 3. and I have following router.js file
import ContactList from '../components/ContactList';
import AddContact from '../components/AddContact';
import { createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router';

const routes = [
    {
        name: 'ContactList',
        path: '/',
        component: ContactList
    },
    {
        name: 'AddContact',
        path: '/add_contact',
        component: AddContact
    },
];

const router = createRouter({    // line 18
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes
})

export default router;

then I lost My Home front end view and inspect got following error errors on the console
createRouter is not defined  routes.js:18
how could I fixed this problem?
I need to solve this problem

You are not importing the function, you should add createRouter to the top imports
